# How to strip google blogger ?view=classic&m=1 parameters from url now self-hosted

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I moved my website off of blogger and still have many google search results that add parameters.  Originally the parameters were only ?m=1 and ?m=0 and I found code to do that but now I'm seeing this:

http://www.shareyourrepair.com/2012/05/dishwasher-door-will-not-open-how-to.html?view=classic&m=1

where there is a ?view=classic added to it.  I would like a htaccess rule that strips every parameter after .html on my incoming requests.  Can someone help me?  This is what I was using to take off the &m=1 and &m=0 parameters and it worked fine:

```
## Remove ?m=1 & ?m=0 From URLs ##
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=0$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$0? [R=301,L]
## Remove ?m=1 & ?m=0 From URLs ##
```

Thank you in advance,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteRule (.+\.html?)$ $1? [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH for responding.  That works on most of (all) the issues I'm having.  Now that I've gone through all the logs, here is a list of all the parameter's I've seen:

Comment: ?m=1&action=backlinks&widgetId=Blog1&widgetType=Blog&responseType=js&postID=3826986253228376322
?view=classic&m=1
?view=flipcard&m=1
?view=magazine&m=1
?view=mosaic&m=1
?view=sidebar&m=1
?view=snapshot&_escaped_fragment_=
?view=snapshot&m=1
?view=timeslide&m=1
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=classic
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=flipcard
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=magazine
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=mosaic
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=snapshot
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=timeslide

Comment: your code doesn't help for the &_escaped_fragment_=?view=snapshot type parameters

Comment: The main parameters that are still not being stripped are as follows:
`&_escaped_fragment_=?view=mosaic
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=snapshot
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=sidebar
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=timeslide
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=magazine
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=flipcard
&_escaped_fragment_=?view=classic`

Thanks again, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You can use: `RewriteRule (.+)$ $1? [NC,R=301,L]` in the last line.

Comment: I just received a whole bunch of 404 errors that seem to point to this code blocking stuff it shouldn't, this is the list of 404 errors I got:

Comment: /wp-content/plugins/auto-attachments/a-a.css
/wp-content/plugins/category-grid-view-gallery/cat_grid.php
/wp-content/plugins/cimy-user-extra-fields/README_OFFICIAL.txt
/wp-content/plugins/ckeditor-for-wordpress/ckeditor.config.js
/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/license.txt
/wp-content/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/index.html
/wp-content/plugins/font-uploader/font-uploader-free.php
/wp-content/plugins/front-end-upload/destination.php
/wp-content/plugins/gallery-plugin/gallery-plugin.php
/wp-content/plugins/mac-dock-gallery/bugslist.txt
/wp-content/plugins/user-photo/admin.css

Comment: /wp-content/plugins/wp-e-commerce/license.txt
/wp-content/plugins/wp-homepage-slideshow/functions.php
/wp-content/plugins/wpstorecart/lgpl.txt

Comment: I didn't see your response before I added the above comments.  You wrote: You can use: RewriteRule (.+)$ $1? [NC,R=301,L] in the last line. Do you mean instead of what you have above or add that below the last line of that code?  What should the code be?

Comment: Yes, block all parameters is not necessarily the soluion, or even a good idea.